# Dompdf generating Blank pdf only for HTML content in Live Server

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using dompdf to generate pdf from html content.
Its working fine in local server.
But after uploading in live linux server, it generates blank pdf instead of that html content. 
then I tried with simple text paragraph,it creates pdf with that paragraph.

> Only for Html contents,it generates blank pdf and only in live
>   server,Locally everything works fine.

This is what Im using,

```
   `require_once '../../dompdf/src/Autoloader.php';
    Dompdf\Autoloader::register();
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();

    $pdf_content = '<span style="width:700px;min-height:500px;background:#ffffff;float:left;font-size:16px;" align="center" id="pdf_content" >
     <span style="width:100%;margin:auto;padding-bottom:10px;">
     <table style="width:100%;text-align:center;margin-top:10px;font-size:14px;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="8">
        <tr>
           <th>Tracking Id</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Passport</th>
           <th>Visa-Ref No.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="reprint" id="59761">
           <td>MAS-59761</td>
           <td>sdafdsf;</td>
           <td><span>dsdsdsd;</span></td>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     </span>
     </span>';      

    $dompdf->loadHtml($pdf_content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $pdf_string = $dompdf->output();
    $filename = uniqid().'.pdf';
    $filepath = '../../forward_pdf_files/'.$filename;
    file_put_contents($filepath, $pdf_string); `
```

Important thing,It doesn't show any error.